# Easiest way to change scale of a Cesium.Rectangle?

Tags: cesiumjs

I want to create a Cesium Rectangle that contains a list of points but is maybe 20% larger in all directions than needed.  What is the easiest way to do that?

```
var rectangle = Cesium.Rectangle.fromCartographicArray(arrayOfCartos);
...how to make rectangle bigger?
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a builtin way in the documentation, so maybe calculating it manually is the way to go:

```
var enlargeFactor = 0.2;
var marginX = rectangle.width * enlargeFactor / 2;
var marginY = rectangle.height * enlargeFactor / 2;
rectangle.east -= marginX;
rectangle.west += marginY;
rectangle.north += marginY;
rectangle.south -= marginY;
```

Comment: erm... i think this will fail completely due to spherical nature of these coordinates, and especially if near the poles

Comment: If so - you cannot represent the result as a rectangle, because scaling while considering the spherical nature might make the lines circular... However in most cases that's close enough to the result. Maybe you can share what is the exact purpose of the scaling? That may change the answer.